# Can I inject a custom (Path)LocationStrategy?

Tags: angular, angular-injector

I'm using a custom [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy):

```
@Injectable() // also tried @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CustomPathLocationStrategy extends PathLocationStrategy {

    constructor() {
        console.log('CustomPathLocationStrategy constructor');
    }

    ....
}
```

To let Angular know about my own implementation in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [ 
{
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: CustomPathLocationStrategy
}
```

This is working fine.

But now I try to inject CustomPathLocationStrategy into a component:

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private custom: CustomPathLocationStrategy) {}
```

The browser console now prints the "CustomPathLocationStrategy constructor" message twice: a new object is created for CustomPathLocationStrategy. This one is different from the one that is used to implement the LocationStrategy.

Am I not supposed to inject CustomPathLocationStrategy in my own components or other services? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a provider. The `provide` property defines the `InjectionToken` or key to identify that provider. The `useClass`, `useFactory`,... only tells the injector how to create that dependency if someone ask for it.

So when you add a provider like this:

```
{
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: CustomPathLocationStrategy
}
```

You are basically telling the app, that if some element asks for a `LocationStrategy`, it should use the `CustomPathLocationStrategy` class to create the dependency and give it back, or if it was already created give that existing instance back.

So in your component, you need to 'ask' for a `LocationStrategy`, and the DI  system will give you back the instance of the `CustomPathLocationStrategy` you've told it to use.

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {}

  ...

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you. It does mean if I inject LocationStrategy I can't call any of my own methods in CustomPathLocationStrategy? Or is it possible to cast?

Comment: You can cast it but it'd be a pain to refactor the app if in the future you decide to revert to the default strategy or change to a new one with a different interface.  I dont know your  exact requirements but if you absolutely need to access the methods of you custom strategy, imo it'd be better to create a second provider after the one you have like `{provide: CustomPathLocationStrategy, useExisting: LocationStrategy}` that re-provide the existing instance, and then inject explicitly the  CustomPathLocationStrategy in your component.